# Variable replacing with array object in Nodejs back end

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

Template from database

```
<p>This is the <strong>default </strong>CKEditor installation.{$name} Source editing is provided by the Source Editing Area</a>&nbsp;plugin.</p><p>Follow the{$city}steps below to try it{$country}out:</p><ul><li>Click the <strong>Source </strong>button to display the HTML source of this tex {$website} {$email}in the source editing area.</li><li>Click the <strong>Source </strong>button again to return to the WYSIWYG view.</li></ul><form>First name:<br>
```

Above HTML code i saved in database. All the variables($name,$city,$country,$website,$email) should replace with below object and create new html template and save to database.

```
[
        {
            "name": "Lijo",
            "city": "Banglaore",
            "country": "India",
            "website": "",
            "email": ""
        },
        {
            "name": "Thoams",
            "city": "Chennai",
            "country": "India",
            "website": "",
            "email": ""
        }]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a weird way to go about such a thing, but whatever floats your boat.  You can use `replace()` to find and replace the placeholders in your template with the values from your objects.

```js
const template = '<p>This is the <strong>default </strong>CKEditor installation.{$name} Source editing is provided by the Source Editing Area</a>&nbsp;plugin.</p><p>Follow the{$city}steps below to try it{$country}out:</p><ul><li>Click the <strong>Source </strong>button to display the HTML source of this tex {$website} {$email}in the source editing area.</li><li>Click the <strong>Source </strong>button again to return to the WYSIWYG view.</li></ul><form>First name:<br>';

const replacements = [{
    "name": "Lijo",
    "city": "Banglaore",
    "country": "India",
    "website": "www.website1.com",
    "email": "email1@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "name": "Thoams",
    "city": "Chennai",
    "country": "India",
    "website": "www.website2.com",
    "email": "email2@gmail.com"
  }
]

const replacedTemplates = replacements.map(replacement => {
  let temporaryTemplate = template;
  
  temporaryTemplate = temporaryTemplate.replace('{$name}', replacement.name);
  temporaryTemplate = temporaryTemplate.replace('{$city}', replacement.city);
  temporaryTemplate = temporaryTemplate.replace('{$country}', replacement.country);
  temporaryTemplate = temporaryTemplate.replace('{$website}', replacement.website);
  temporaryTemplate = temporaryTemplate.replace('{$email}', replacement.email);
  
  return temporaryTemplate;
});

console.log(replacedTemplates);
```